# Removing Duplicate Lines from JQuery Autocomplete TextBox

Tags: jquery, mysql

My datasource returns up to 3 different values for each item:  name, a company name, and an email address

The problem is, this ends up returning the same company names multiple times in the returned list of suggestions.

I want to remove these duplicate values from the list using jquery code.

Comment: SELECT DISTINCT column_name(s)
FROM table_name

Answer (score 0):

> Most probably you are doing with some JOIN functions and there by
>   joining multiple tables.To avoid duplicate in the results,you need to
>   do that on the server side i mean the part which fetches company name
>   email and address add a GROUP BY to your SQL Query

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM some_table GROUP BY your_table_primary_key"
```

Comment: I am using node and underscore.js in my application.I want to implement the at client side not on server side and cant use sql queries in my code.I want an method which will remove duplicate value from search list and display the final list

Comment: So from where do you get the company name and other details ?